# Logically questionable?

Tags: java

```
double x = 1; 
double y = 3 * (1.0 / 3); 


x == y
```

In a powerpoint I am studying, it said the statement is logically questionable. I cannot find out why it is thus, I mean you use == for primitives correct, or is it Logically questionable because doubles are not stored exactly or am I missing something obvious? Thanks

Comment: Don't doubles involve decimals and 1 and 3 do not?

Comment: It's the latter. Doubles are have limited precision and rounding errors accumulate.

Comment: *Which* statement is logically questionable? The comparison expression is logically questionable because you aren't using the result anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you've got it: since the data types are doubles, rather than int or Integer, the resulting x and y may not be precisely equal.

Comment: i was about to answer when I saw this one, so thought I'll add to it. its the use of "double" that makes it tricky! there's no guarantee that this will evaluate to true always. y can be 0.9999, or 1.00001

Comment: Cool. I think Jonathan Newmuis's answer is better than mine anyway.

Comment: If you use `int` 3*(1/3) != 1. ;)

Answer (score 3):

It is logically questionable because the compare statement at the end would evaluate to false.  Doubles are stored as a series of powers of two.  So values like  1/2 and 1/4 and 1/8  could actually be expressed in floating point formats exactly,  but not 1/3.  It will be approximated to 1/4 + 1/64 + ...   there is now way it could exactly be apprroximate 1/3

Correct way to compare the floats is like this:

```
Math.double.abs ( x - y ) > tol
```

where tol is set to something sufficiently small, depending on your application.  For example most graphics applications work well with tol = 0.00001

Answer (score 2):

Because `1.0 / 3` is `0.3333...`, up to the capacity of a `double`.  `3 * 0.3333...` is `0.9999...`, up to the capacity of a double.

So we have the question `1 == 0.9999...`, which I guess you could call "logically questionable".

Comment: Careful there - [`1` does actually equal `0.999...`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...)

Comment: `1` equals `0.999...` where there are an infinite number of 9's.  But this is not an infinite number of 9's, so they would not be equal in this case.  But as others have mentioned here, it all depends on doubles' rounding.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of roundoff error. The problem is analogous to the precision problems you have have with decimals when dealing with numbers that cannot be precisely expressed in the format you are using.

For example, with six digits of decimal precision, the best you can do for 1/3 is `.333333`. But:

`1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3` -> .33333 + .333333 + .33333 = .999999 `!= 1.000000`

Ouch. For 2/3, you can use either `.666666` or `.666667` but either way, you have problems.

If 2/3 -> `.666666` then:
`2/3 + 1/3` -> .333333 + .666666 `!= 1.000000`

Ouch.

And if 2/3. -> `.666667` then:
`1/3 * 2 - 2/3` -> .333333 * 2.00000 - .666667 = .666666 - .666667 `!= 0`

Ouch.

It's analogous with doubles. [This paper](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) is considered the authoritative work on the subject. In simple terms -- never compare floating point numbers for equality unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Comment: correct. the floats and doubles are stored as powers of 2 not as decimals.  Which will make things even worse in case of 1/3.

Answer (score 0):

> Logically questionable because doubles are not stored exactly

More or less.

- As a general rule, a `double` cannot represent the precise value of a Real number.  The value `1/3` is an example.
- Some numbers *can* be represented precisely as `double` values.  `1.0` and `3.0` are examples.  However, the division operator produces a number (in this case) that cannot be represented.
- In general, any code that uses `==` to compare `double` or `float` values is questionable ... in the sense that you need to analyse each case carefully to know whether the use of `==` is correct.  (And the analysis is not intuitive for people who were taught at a very early age to do arithmetic in base 10!)
- From the software engineering standpoint, the fact that you *need* to do a case-by-case analysis of `==` usage makes it questionable practice.  Good software engineering is (in part) about eliminating mistakes and sources of mistakes.